# Find the average, median, mode, and range

Tags: code-golf

It's easier to put this into coding terminology, so here we go:

1. First find the average, median, mode, and range.
2. Then, put those values in another array, then find the new average, median, mode, and range.
3. Bonus -10 bytes (yeah, negative bytes, because there's already answers) for programs that can handle this many times (repeat the first steps N times with an extra parameter)
4. Then average those numbers. If there are multiple medians or modes, simply average them!

### Test cases:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> 2.5625
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 0.9375
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97] -> 48.5
[0, 5, 10, 50] -> 24.375
[4, 4, 8, 10, 16, 24, 100, 150, 200, 200, 250] -> 136.7045454545454545454545454545... (it's fine if there's floating-point inaccuracies)
```

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Specifically for mode, how should we handle arrays where there are _two_ most-common values (e.g., `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]`)? Is that a situation we need to deal with or can we assume that won't come up?

Comment: @cocomac Thanks, fixed it!

Comment: In my opinion, this is a boring challenge. It is a mishmash of existing challenges, and the way it is mixed is boring and uncreative. Explaining the downvote.

Comment: Related to Seggan's comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20905/36398. Regarding bonus: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/36398

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 28 - 10 = 18 bytes

```
(λṁn∆ṁwfṁnDvOÞMİṁn₌Gg-WW;†)ṁ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuItBIiwiIiwiKM674bmBbuKIhuG5gXdm4bmBbkR2T8OeTcSw4bmBbuKCjEdnLVdXO+KAoCnhuYEiLCIiLCIzLCBbMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNV1cbjMsIFsxLCAxLCAxLCAxLCAxXVxuMywgWzIsIDMsIDUsIDcsIDExLCAxMywgMTcsIDE5LCAyMywgMjksIDMxLCAzNywgNDEsIDQzLCA0NywgNTMsIDU5LCA2MSwgNjcsIDcxLCA3MywgNzksIDgzLCA4OSwgOTddXG4zLCBbMCwgNSwgMTAsIDUwXVxuMywgWzQsIDQsIDgsIDEwLCAxNiwgMjQsIDEwMCwgMTUwLCAyMDAsIDIwMCwgMjUwXSJd)

A horrible mess of `n`s, `ṁ`s and other letters.

### Explained

```
(λṁn∆ṁwfṁnDvOÞMİṁn₌Gg-WW;†)ṁ
(                         )  # first inputh times
 λ                      ;†   # do to argument n:
  ṁ                          #  mean of n
   n∆ṁwfṁ                    #  average of medians of n
         nDvOÞMİṁ            #  average of modes of n. If it was smallest mode or first mode, this could just be ∆M
                 ₌Gg-        #  range of n
                     WW      #  wrap into a list
                           ṁ # average of that
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 14 (24  [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) - 10 bonus)

```
ƒD©Åm®Ð¢ZQÏ®Zsß-)ε¸˜ÅA]н
```

First input is \$n\$, second is the list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9vc2FiaWX//8aSRMKpw4Vtwq7DkMKiWlHDj8KuWnPDny0pzrXCuMucw4VBXdC9//8yClswLDUsMTAsNTBd) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##LY0xCsJAEEWvErYTvpLZ3WSzVRC8gI1FQgoFCwuxCAg5QGyV1IJgZ5NOsLHZBRtBPIMXiRMIwwzvD3/@7MrlarPu9lUqgt@hCURaSdG9mpm7@XrrWn9y12zuj67NSn8Zjz5393iffT0tvs9OTBbo8pwgoaARFWAeirnfRjAglgrEYCEVpIUiKANN0HxnELHPIibEBoZgFIxFopBYWMNBIccQj5BZ86OkVxRDagamKIQMh2ZT8Qc).

**Explanation:**

```python
ƒ        # Loop the first (implicit) input + 1 amount of times:
 D       #  Duplicate the current list
         #  (which will be the second implicit input-list in the first iteration)
 ©       #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
  Åm     #  Pop and get its mean
 ®       #  Push list `®` again
  Ð      #  Triplicate it
   ¢     #  Pop both copies, and get the count of each value
    Z    #  Push the maximum (without popping the list of counts)
     Q   #  Check which counts are equal to this maximum
      Ï  #  Only keep the values at those truthy values
 ®       #  Push list `®` yet again
  Z      #  Push its maximum (without popping the list)
   s     #  Swap so the list is at the top of the stack
    ß    #  Pop and push its minimum
     -   #  Subtract the minimum from the maximum
 )       #  Wrap all four items on the stack into a list
  ε      #  Map over this quadruplet:
   ¸     #   Wrap it in a list (for the fourth item; and optionally the mean)
    ˜    #   Flatten it (in case it was already a list)
     ÅA  #   Get the average of this
]        # Close both the map and loop
 н       # Pop and push the first item (the average of the extra iteration)
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```